# Pandas extract daily data and write to csv

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe looking like this:

```
Index                   Stat    value1  value2  value3  value4  value5  value6 
2016-11-01 00:00:00.000 Gard    0.08    0.24    0.09    6.08    18.4    0.268514431642
2016-11-01 00:00:00.100 Gard    0.08    0.24    0.09    6.08    18.4    0.268514431642
2016-11-01 00:00:00.200 Gard    0.08    0.24    0.09    6.08    18.4    0.268514431642
2016-11-01 00:00:00.300 Gard    0.08    0.24    0.09    6.08    18.4    0.268514431642
2016-11-01 00:00:00.400 Gard    0.08    0.24    0.09    6.08    18.4    0.268514431642
2016-11-02 00:00:00.000 Gard    0.08    0.24    0.09    6.08    18.4    0.268514431642
2016-11-02 00:00:00.100 Gard    0.08    0.24    0.09    6.08    18.4    0.268514431642
2016-11-02 00:00:00.200 Gard    0.15    0.25    0.01    6.08    31.0    0.291719042916
2016-11-02 00:00:00.300 Gard    0.15    0.25    0.01    6.08    31.0    0.291719042916
```

Of course this is just a snippet, the whole dataframe has about 4.3 million rows.

I would like to extract each line that correponds to a date. So all lines that have the timestamp date 2016-11-01 into one file and 2016-1-02 into another file. So two files looking like this:

```
Index                   Stat    value1  value2  value3  value4  value5  value6
2016-11-01 00:00:00.000 Gard    0.08    0.24    0.09    6.08    18.4    0.268514431642
2016-11-01 00:00:00.100 Gard    0.08    0.24    0.09    6.08    18.4    0.268514431642
2016-11-01 00:00:00.200 Gard    0.08    0.24    0.09    6.08    18.4    0.268514431642
2016-11-01 00:00:00.300 Gard    0.08    0.24    0.09    6.08    18.4    0.268514431642
2016-11-01 00:00:00.400 Gard    0.08    0.24    0.09    6.08    18.4    0.268514431642
```

And:

```
Index                   Stat    value1  value2  value3  value4  value5  value6
2016-11-02 00:00:00.000 Gard    0.08    0.24    0.09    6.08    18.4    0.268514431642
2016-11-02 00:00:00.100 Gard    0.08    0.24    0.09    6.08    18.4    0.268514431642
2016-11-02 00:00:00.200 Gard    0.15    0.25    0.01    6.08    31.0    0.291719042916
2016-11-02 00:00:00.300 Gard    0.15    0.25    0.01    6.08    31.0    0.291719042916
```

I tried to use `groupby` in the following command:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(df.index.date)["Stat","value1","value2","value3","value4","value5","value6"]
```

But I don't get any output or error. It runs but nothing happens. Am I doing anything wrong? Is this even the correct function to use? Or is there an easier, better way?

Comment: For the record, `groupby` returns a `GroupBy` object on which you can apply functions such as sum, mean, or even custom functions.

Comment: Okay that explains why I got nothing back from running the `groupby` command. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply` and custom function with [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
f = lambda x: x.to_csv(r'd:/folder/{}.csv'.format(x.name))
df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(f)
```

Comment: `x.name` is just the path where to save the data?

Comment: give me some time ;) but x.name is file name without path